# How to fix Laravel project that renders properly only on computers other than my own?

Tags: css, laravel, heroku

My OS X computer won't render a specific Laravel projecect properly. I can log in, but it seems all the CSS is blocked. It improperly looks like this:

[image]

It should however look like this:

[image]

My friend who did most of the coding has a Mac as well, and it works on his computer. But not mine. I didn't code any of it. I tried 3 browsers (FF, Chrome, Safari) all to no avail. It works on my Android phone and another Windows computer.

It is visible here: https://shielded-lowlands-91684.herokuapp.com/

I can share the repo on Gitlab (https://gitlab.com/kaspis912/blog) or Heroku. However Gitlab I need to add a person individually because it is private.

I can also add individual files that will help here. Here is one:
App.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Blog') }}</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <!-- Branding Image -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                        {{ config('app.name') }}
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    @if(Auth::user())
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="{{ route('articles.index') }}">Articles</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    @endif

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
                        @else
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                            onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                            Logout
                                        </a>

                                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a id="delete-btn" href="#">
                                            Delete Account
                                        </a>
                                        <form id="delete-form" method="POST" action="{{ route('users.destroy', Auth::id()) }}" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                                            {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                                            {{csrf_field()}}
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        @yield('content')
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    <script>
        $('.confirm-delete').on('click', function(event){
            return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');
        });

        $('#delete-btn').on('click', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var confirm_delete = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete your account?');
            if(confirm_delete== true){
                $('#delete-form').submit();
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is some of what happens when I try to inspect element in chrome. It seems some of the CSS gets greyed out. I do not know why.[image]

Comment: Try hosting the assets (css/js) via https too.

Comment: Show the views code

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz I just now added app.blade.php, and can add more as necessary.

Comment: @Tuim, where can I look to find that? I am more familiar with Ruby on Rails, but I am happy to look if you let me know what file that would be in. I included app.blade.php if that is any assistance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `secure_asset`

change these 2 lines

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

**with**

```
<link href="{{ secure_asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ secure_asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```